# Please override _params with your desired parameter security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

Im developing simple extension for RefineryCMS.
I've already have it in my admin panel. 
I have problem with saving. Logs tell me

```
RuntimeError (Please override block_params with your desired parameter security.):
  (eval):157:in `block_params'
  (eval):15:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
```

I cant find what I need to overrride.
Thank you for advices!

Comment: can you show your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a bundle update:

```
bundle update
```

Got that from this [discussion](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2428).

Also, check if you have `block_params` defined in `blocks/admin/blocks_controller.rb` file. If not add:

```
  def block_params
    params.require(:block).permit(. . . )
  end
```